# Calculate Opamp output

Tags: operational-amplifier

I found below circuit in one of our old designs and I am trying to figure out How to calculate the output gain.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxpPz2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I think I found answer to it in [this](https://file:///C:/Users/amir.eshraghi.Analytical/Downloads/Design_of_Current_Sources_for_Load_Common_Mode_Opt.pdf)  paper, but still reviewing it

Comment: What methods do you know for making such a calculation?

Comment: @jonk I know Nodal analyze if that works. I even tried doing it but got to no where
Vout = V1 = V2 = V3/2

Comment: Are you able to show what you tried? It would help me do a little less, if you are close. And yes, nodal works. Did you account for the output current of the opamp?

Comment: I get:$$\frac{V_{_\text{OUT}}}{V_{_\text{IN}}}=\frac{1}{1-\frac{R_1 \,R_3}{R_2 \,R_4}}$$With the values you have in place, the divisor is zero and that's probably not so good. If you need to me to show you how to get there, I can.

Comment: @jonk Thanks I am trying to put everything down so I can upload it

Comment: It looks like an inverting Howland current pump gone wrong. Hint: are you sure you have interpreted the circuit correctly?

Comment: @Andyaka No that how the circuit is

Comment: Shahreza. . I agree with @Andyaka. . the circuit does exactly resemble a Howland current source. At least look up the Howland circuit before objecting. I have used the circuit in several designs.

Comment: @Marla this is exactly how it is. It is similar to howland circuit but positive and negative is reverse.

Comment: @jonk I put how I did put my work so you can take look at it. just one question base on your result the  Vout/Vin = infinity

Comment: @Marla this more similar to enhanced  Howland current source

Comment: @Shareza There are answers here which, as usual, seriously and unnecessarily over complicate the issue to the point of making it non-understandable but the simple and accurate answer is that that circuit, as it stands, will saturate!

Answer (score 9):

This circuit is a standard building block from the toolbox (a Howland current source). It does little of value with no load on the output (just saturates, because the load is infinite resistance and it can't maintain a constant current because the op-amp output voltage is limited to the supply rails, at best).

When loaded with a resistor (or other impedance) to ground it does something interesting and (very) occasionally useful.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ff7bp7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Suggest you calculate Vout as a function of the load resistance or impedance.

Ideally, the output impedance is infinite, as you would expect of a current source.

[image]

Comment: Can you tell me  what is output current will be in function

Comment: And deprive you of the fun?

Answer (score 7):

Wow. Lots of answers. None of them apply the math, though. Yet.

I always take what Spehro says, seriously. I've not encountered this as a Howland -- I'm a hobbyist and no professional -- but I'll address his comment mathematically, as well.

Let's start without the load that Spehro mentions and see where that goes. I'll use [SymPy](https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html) and the assumption of an ideal opamp:

```
var('v1 v3 vout vin r1 r2 r3 r4 iout')
eq1 = Eq( v1/r1 + v1/r2, vin/r1 + v3/r2 )
eq2 = Eq( v3/r2 + v3/r3, iout + v1/r2 + vout/r3 )
eq3 = Eq( vout/r3 + vout/r4, v3/r3 )
eq4 = Eq( v1, vout )
solve( [ eq1, eq2, eq3, eq4 ], [ iout, v1, v3, vout ] )[vout]/vin
-r2*r4/(r1*r3 - r2*r4)
```

This results in:

$$\frac{V_{_\text{OUT}}}{V_{_\text{IN}}}=\frac{1}{1-\frac{R_1 \,R_3}{R_2 \,R_4}}$$

So, unloaded, that's the result. If all the resistor values are equal, as you show, then the voltage gain will be *very high* (as none of the resistor values will be exactly the same as each other.) Also, I assumed an ideal opamp. Real ones have finite open loop gain, output resistance, and input resistance. So reality is merely that the voltage gain will be fairly high.

Now, assuming the gain is very high, let's address Spehro's comment in his answer. Assume loaded by \$Z\$:

```
var('v1 v3 vout vin r1 r2 r3 r4 iout Z')
eq1 = Eq( v1/r1 + v1/r2, vin/r1 + v3/r2 )
eq2 = Eq( v3/r2 + v3/r3, iout + v1/r2 + vout/r3 )
eq3 = Eq( vout/r3 + vout/r4 + vout/Z, v3/r3 )
eq4 = Eq( v1, vout )
solve( [ eq1, eq2, eq3, eq4 ], [ iout, v1, v3, vout ] )[vout]/vin
-Z*r2*r4/(Z*r1*r3 - Z*r2*r4 + r1*r3*r4)
```

Or,

$$\frac{V_{_\text{OUT}}}{V_{_\text{IN}}}=\frac{1}{1-\frac{R_1 \,R_3}{R_2 \,R_4}-\frac{R_1 \,R_3}{R_2 \,Z}}$$

If all the resistor values are close to each other, \$R=R_1=R_2=R_3=R_4\$, then this is approximately:

$$\frac{V_{_\text{OUT}}}{V_{_\text{IN}}}=-\frac{Z}{R}$$

Let's say that you have \$R\approx 1\:\text{k}\Omega\$. And let's say you apply a \$1\:\text{V}\$ peak AC sine wave at \$1\:\text{kHz}\$ at the input. And let's say that \$Z\$ is a \$150\:\text{nF}\$ capacitor (whose \$X_{_\text{C}}\$ will be near the same magnitude as the resistor values) in series with a \$1\:\text{k}\Omega\$ resistor. We'd compute a magnitude of about \$\mid \,Z\mid\:\approx 1.456\:\text{k}\Omega\$. So we'd expect a peak to peak output of about \$2\cdot 1.456\approx 2.9\$. You can try this out in Spice to see what you get. I'd guess it would be pretty close, though.

let's try LTspice using an LT1800 opamp:

```
XU1 OUT N001 Vcc Vee N002 LT1800
R1 N001 IN 1k
R2 N002 N001 1k
V1 IN 0 SINE(0 1 1k)
R3 OUT N002 1k
R4 0 OUT 1k
C1 OUT 0 150n Rser=1k
V99 Vcc 0 15
V98 0 Vee 15
.tran 0 1 .99
.meas TRAN RMSVO RMS V(OUT)
.meas TRAN RMSVI RMS V(IN)
.meas GAIN PARAM {RMSVO/RMSVI}
```

From which I find:

```
gain: (rmsvo/rmsvi)=1.46112
```

This is very close to the predicted value of \$1.456\$.

Comment: AS a hobbyist, I'm sure you have spent 1000x times more working on transistor theory than any University training. and Pro's do the math a few times and can see the results in their head after that or on simulation for the nitty gritty like impedance sweeps.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 But if you know the math, is there any reason not to do it? I personally find satisfaction solving problems with rigor and mathematics.

Comment: @Carl This is where Tony and I part company. A great deal of practical experience allows even a blind man to find their way in common circuit patterns, by feel. But one who ***sees*** through powerful theory can face any situation, new or old, and find their way through. Or can generate new situations never before faced and solved. (Better is to possessing both theory and lots of practical experience, of course. My experience is spotty and I don't consider that a good thing. It just is.)

Comment: @jonk Maybe Tony is like Bob Pease, whose favorite programming language was solder. Or like Jim Williams who hated the LaPlace transform (no offense, btw).

Comment: My former brilliant boss with a PhD and could repair import car engines to get thru school's favorite tool was the pencil. Mine is Falstad now but wasn't avail during my career. I preferred solder done by techs. But I did invent SCADA in 1977 with about 200 channels and robotics.i was promoted to Sr Eng before 5 yrs and got a 25% raise

Comment: i don't like analyzing lame designs that I recognize instantly, I prefer to simulate better ones. like what happens when you overcome input offset with no load? what is the BDV for required and always start with expected/desired outcomes. Or da SPECS.Always use tolerances and determine sensitivity to each variable and include real ESR, DCR , Rs for every component. that's another way we differ,

Comment: i also prefer to answer XY questions with better answers unasked.

Answer (score 3):

This acts as a comparator with 50% duty cycle if using a +/- supply.

The unity gain differential amp is changed to use the output as a reference instead of 0V on differential input.

So it has open loop voltage gain with an output impedance of 500 ohms **with no load.**

Since the output is at Vin+ the amplitude is 50% of Vcc and 50% of Vee.

Coincidentally this is also a Howland Current source when a load is applied to output.

**Since no load was provided in the question, the response to no-load with a Howland current source is to saturate the output at full amplitude  (V=I*∞) and divide by 2 at the input.(+)**

The intention of this design might have been to reduce stray pF effects on input rise time but you are still limited by GBW effects and current limiting. (In hypothetical theory) but in practice, it only serves to shunt injected noise currents on input with a 1k input impedance rather than >>1M. Yet that could have been done with 1 less R using input shunt R, but then that makes it prone to overvoltage on input.

### It seems more likely the OP forgot to add the load and it was intended as a V to I circuit.

The transfer function is \$Io = -V_{in}/1~k \Omega\$

It is easily done to swap inputs on the left side and make this non-inverting.

Comment: One question if the output is reference what is point of R3

Comment: It serves a purpose with R4 to 1/2 of Vout. To simplify the circuit. Remove R2, isolate from Out. At Vin+ and ground it.

Comment: Sorry I did not have any load on circuit neither. I draw exactly what it was in old document.

Comment: Now you know.....

Answer (score 0):

The output will saturate either positively or negatively.

Assuming a dual supply for the op amp. If the input is greater than 0V then the output will saturate negatively. If the input is less than 0V then the output will saturate positively.

This is because any input will cause the output to drive into saturation in a desperate and failing attempt to make the two inputs equal to each other (V1=V2).

Answer (score 0):

You can express I1 (current through R1 and R2) using Vopo.

**(Vopo - Vin) = -I1 * (R1 + R2)**

You can express I2 (current through R3 and R4) using Vopo.

**(Vopo - 0) = (I2) * (R3 + R4)**

You have 3 variables: I1, I2, Vopo, and only two equations.

For the third equation, let's first express **V2** and **V1**:

***V2 = I2 * R4***

***V1 = Vin - I1 * R1***

(Notice I assigned current directions I1, and I2 clockwise in both cases - if this is wrong, the current will turn out negative at the solution).

**(V2 - V1) * 100k = Vopo** (assuming that the op amp's gain 100k)

**(I2 * R4 - (Vin - I1 * R1)) * 100k = Vopo** (Eq. III)

Now you have 3 equations in 3 variables.

If Vopo comes out within your voltage range (say -15 V to 15 V), that's the right solution (or one of the right solutions if Saturated solutions are also valid).

If Vopo comes outside that range (i.e. 25 V), then plug in 15 V or -15 V for Vopo, and scrap the 3rd equation because it doesn't hold for a Saturated Op Amp.

If in a Saturated solution for Vopo = 15 V, the solution comes to have V2 < V1, you have to plug in -15 V, or vice versa.

If you hit the Saturated range, in many cases either solution will do, and the real result will depend on Hysteresis (the solution to which the Op Amp's transistors are closer to at the moment when they face the new condition your schematic describes).

Note: it's possible to see the result simply by looking at the feedbacks involved, but outlined is an analytical approach through equations (that's how a circuit simulator would approach it).